# How to copy companion object and make changes without reflecting these changes to the original object?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, kotlin, companion-object

I am using companion object to temprorarily save some data.

I might want to change this data and also i want to make sure that original object is not changed when i make changes.

I tried this.

```
companion object{
        var position: Int = 0
    } 
var copyPosition = positon
copyPosition--
println(copyPosition)
```

This works perfectly fine and prints -1. Original `position` is not changed. (value 0 is not changed.)

**However**, the same operations with `List<MyObject>` is not working.

```
companion object{
        var list: MutableList<MyObject> = "...here objects are aquired..."
    } 
var tempList: MutableList<MyObject> = list
tempList.removeAt(0)
println(list.size)
```

Here, if i remove item from `tempList`, the original list also loses this item. How can i stop this? How can the changes be only made to `tempList` but not original `list`?

Comment: When you try to copy it using the `=` it will only copy the reference to the original list and not the value of the list. Use `var tempList: MutableList<MyObject> = list.toMutableList()`

Comment: Are you looking for "deep" or "shallow" copy? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `tempList` the reference of the list of `Companion object`. Any changes made are also reflected in the list. What you could do is to create a new `MutableList<MyOjbect)` and `.addAll()` all objects of `list` to your new `MutableList` object

### Example

```
val firstList = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5)  //0x543DE (Dummy memory address)

val secondList = firstList  //Giving reference of firstList to the secondList  //0x543DE
```

As you can see,  `secondList = firstList`, we are giving reference of `firstList` to the `secondList`. Think it like this, your `firstList` val **holds a reference** to the original list object. And when we wrote `secondList = firstList`, we are giving `secondList` with the reference of the list that `firstList` val was pointing to. Now both of these `val` point to the same object in the memory.

Now changes made in `secondList` are also reflected to the 'original' list. But why? You guessed it, since both of them point to the same object.

As for the solution, you could:

```
companion object{
    var list: MutableList<MyObject> = "...here objects are aquired..."
} 
var tempList: MutableList<MyObject> = mutableListOf()
tempList.addAll(list) //This will iteratively copy list items to tempList
tempList.removeAt(0)
println(list.size)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know that i am saving the reference to the original list.